# Terraform how to create a block of code based on a conditions

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I'm trying to create a resource with a creation condition for the github_configuration block, but I don't find such an option.
Depending on the environment I need or don't need git config.
I can't figure out how I can set up such a dependency

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "myDataFactory" {
  name                = var.datafactortyName
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.myResourceGroup.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myResourceGroup.name

  dynamic "github_configuration" {
  #count = var.Environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  for_each = var.Environment == "dev"

    content {
      account_name    = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.AccountName : null
      branch_name     = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.Branch : null
      git_url         = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.RepoUrl : null
      repository_name = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.RepoName : null
      root_folder     = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.RepoFolder : null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `github_configuration` block optional, you can do:

```
  dynamic "github_configuration" {

    for_each = var.Environment == "dev" ? [1] : []

    content {
      account_name    = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.AccountName : null
      branch_name     = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.Branch : null
      git_url         = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.RepoUrl : null
      repository_name = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.RepoName : null
      root_folder     = var.Environment == "dev" ? var.RepoFolder : null
    }
  }
}
```

`[1]` ensures that `for_each` executes ones. Actual value of `1` is irrelevant. It can be any value, as long as the list have one element.